# Output ALL results?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I've been trying to create my own forum script in ColdFusion, but sadly, it's a lot more difficult then I thought that it would be. I'm getting stuck when trying to display ALL the comments from the database, because ColdFusion throws me errors.

> *The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.*
>
> **Error Occurred While Processing Request**
>
> #### Element USERNAME is undefined in REAGEER.
>
> The error occured in **C:/inetpub/wwwroot/content/1-Home/topicview.cfm: line 197**
>
> ```
> 195:
> 196:         <div id="pers_info">
> 197:         <a href="/">#reageer.username#</a> <cfif #reageer.online# is 1><img src="http://www.wonderhotel.nl/archive/icons/mini/habbo_online_anim.gif"></img><cfelse><img src="http://www.wonderhotel.nl/archive/icons/mini/habbo_offline.gif"></img></cfif></strong>
> 198:         <p>Berichten: 55</p>
> 199:
> ```

The code I wrote for this script is the following:

```
<cfif IsDefined('URL.id') and URL.id neq ""> // Get the topic ID
<cfquery name = "comments" datasource = "#DSN#">
SELECT *
FROM  `forum_comments`
WHERE topicid = #id#
</cfquery> // Get the comments

  <cfif #comments.RecordCount# is 1>

<cfquery name = "reageer" datasource = "#DSN#">
SELECT *
FROM  `users`
WHERE id = #comments.poster#
</cfquery> // Get the comment posters
</cfif>

                        <cfset colour ="post_uneven">

  <cfloop query="comments">

<div id="#colour#">

        <div id="pers_info">
        <a href="/">#reageer.username#</a> <cfif #reageer.online# is 1><img src="http://www.wonderhotel.nl/archive/icons/mini/habbo_online_anim.gif"></img><cfelse><img src="http://www.wonderhotel.nl/archive/icons/mini/habbo_offline.gif"></img></cfif>
        <p>Berichten: 55</p>

<cfquery name = "reageer_badge_one" datasource = "#DSN#">
SELECT *
FROM  `user_badges`
WHERE user_id = '#reageer.id#'
AND badge_slot = 1
</cfquery>
<cfquery name = "reageer_badge_second" datasource = "#DSN#">
SELECT *
FROM  `user_badges`
WHERE user_id = '#reageer.id#'
AND badge_slot = 2
</cfquery>

                <div id="pers_info_habbo">
                <img src="http://habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=#reageer.look#.gif">
                </div>

                        <div id="pers_info_grbadge">
                <cfif #reageer_badge_one.RecordCount# is 1>
                <img src="http://wonderhotel.nl/Public/Images/badges/#reageer_badge_one.badge_id#.gif">
                </cfif>
                </div>

                <div id="pers_info_badge">
                <cfif #reageer_badge_second.RecordCount# is 1>
                <img src="http://wonderhotel.nl/Public/Images/badges/#reageer_badge_second.badge_id#.gif">
                </cfif>
                </div>

                <div id="pers_info_missie">
                #reageer.motto#
                </div>
        </div>


        <div id="post_text">

                <a href="/"><div id="post_text_edit" title="Bericht aanpassen"></div></a>
                <a href="/"><div id="post_text_delete" title="Bericht verwijderen"></div></a>

                <div id="post_text_title">
                RE: #gettopic.title#
                </div>

                <div id="post_text_date">
                #DateFormat(dateAdd("s", comments.timestamp, "01/01/1970"))# #TimeFormat(dateAdd("s", comments.timestamp, "01/01/1970"))#
                </div>

                <div id="post_text_text">
                #comments.text#

                </div>

        </div>
</div></div>


        <cfif colour is "post_uneven"><cfset colour="post_even"><cfelse><cfset colour="post_uneven"></cfif>
                                        </cfloop>

        </cfoutput>




<div id="topic_info_balk"> // Useless
<div id="forum_paginas">
    Bekijk pagina:
    1
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">7</a>
    <a href="#">8</a>
    <a href="#">9</a>
    <a href="#">10</a>
    <a href="#">>></a>
</div>

<div id="reageer-topic">

                                <a href="/topic/<cfoutput>#gettopic.id#</cfoutput>/comment">Reageer</a>
                </div>

</div>
</div>
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, and why ColdFusion gives me this error. I would appreciate all the help! My only guess is that ColdFusion tries to get all the data (again) from the poster of the first comment, but that would be wrong because I want to get comment 1, comment 2, and afterwards 3, 4, 5, etcetera.

Also, when adding the first comment to the topic, everything works fine. But after adding the second, I get the error that you can see above.

Regards,
Yannick

Comment: Pro tip: never use `SELECT *` in scripts or software. Always enumerate the columns you want to retrieve. It seems likely that there's something wrong with `username` as a column name.

Comment: Thanks! I'll enumerate them. The weird part is that there is nothing wrong with the username column when the topic has 1 comment, because the error only occurs when 2 comments are posted..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that since you have a `<cfif>` around the "reageer" query, the error is occurring because there is more than 1 comment, but the output for the `username` is not wrapped in a `<cfif>` as well. Therefore, ColdFusion is trying to get the value of `username` from a query that doesn't exist (because the `<cfif>` prevented it from executing), hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured out what was causing the problem, the RecordCount function only showed the correct output when the RecordCount of the comments was 1, when there were more comments the <cfif> tag would cause to malfunction, so I fixed it by changing the cfif tag to   <cfif #comments.RecordCount# gte 1>

There is just one last thing, because now it shows the same author for every comment, but that's not how it should be

Comment: Fyi - You don't need # inside an if statement

Comment: Learning a lot of new things today - thanks a lot! I've removed all of them.

Comment: @Yannick good rule of thumb is unless you're specifically outputting something to a page you almost never need them. Feel free to post your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you want any pointers.

Comment: You're getting the same author for every comment because you're looping over the comments, but the query for the author details occurs *outside* that loop. So the query for author is only occurring for the  first comment, and is just reused for each iteration of the loop. If you move the query inside the loop, it should work. A better approach, however, would be to retrieve the comment and comment author data in the same query. Not only will that tremendously simplify your code, but will reduce the number of queries that ColdFusion has to make to the database (which will increase performance).

Comment: In fact, although I don't know how your tables are related, it seems like you could probably combine all the queries you have on this page into one. Then you'd literally only have to loop over the comments, wouldn't have to worry about the "ifs", and could have one query to deal with in terms of creating your rendered content.

Comment: You're right, I combined almost all of them into one single query and it cleaned up a lot of unnecessary code. Thank you so much for your help!